# Obfuscation using Proguard makes my application not work

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

I used Proguard to obfuscate the source code. After obfuscating, the application is not working. Any specific reasons? Has anyone faced this kind of problem?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? Give errors you see, details.

Comment: no errors.  A jar file is created as output.  When i run the jar file, the functionalities are not working, it was a swing application.  The normal file (before obfuscating) works fine

Comment: *"the functionalities are not working"* Be specific.

Comment: it is a JTextarea, where syntax highlighting is done for customised code.  the highlighting part is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude specific code/packages from obfuscation till you found the exact offensive code. Obvious culprits like `Class.forName` and using `java.reflect` can be sought in the source code.

Probably on the proguard site some more tips are given.

Comment: +1 i excluded some features in shrink, and excluded some in obfuscate.  You are right, Class.forName might be the culprit. It is totally unreadable in class decompiler. Thanks